# JMenu displaying behind Label

Tags: java, swing, label, awt, mixing

[image]

Statdard is Lable  When i am opening file JMenu, label is displaying in front of jmenu. It was happening because I was mixing AWT and swings. Instead of Label when i used JLabel It is working fine as expected.

[Mixing AWT and Swing components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit)

Comment: can downvoter to share your whatever

Comment: Not downvoter, but some code would really help here.

Comment: not there no code required, [this is booking example about](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was mixing AWT and swing. Sorry it was `Label` not `JLabel`. Found help from these two articles:

- [*Abstract Window Toolkit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit).
- [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: Please delete this and add the information to your original post. Use the "edit" link.

Comment: that's one of the reasons to show an SSCCE: either you find the mix-up yourself quicker, or more eyes looking at it will :-)